# Selenide not taking screenshot on failures any longer

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, geckodriver, selenide

**Spec:**

- Selenide-4.12.2
- Selenium 3.13.0
- GeckoDriver
- Maven
- Fitnesse-20180127
- Fitlibrary 2.0

I am not sure what changed in the recent builds particularly on the versions that support gecko webdriver but I no longer get the screenshot location url upon failures and it is very frustrating since I will like to know what was on the screen upon failure. See attached image. Notice no image url. Do I need to turn this on in the configuration or is this some type of know defect?
[image]

Note the older version of Selenide which I have on a separate box does take screenshot upon every failure

[image]

Comment: Try to update your selenide version. Maybe this solve your problem.

Comment: I have throttled between several version particularly the newer versions that use the geckodriver to no avail. The only option will be go back to older builds which I don't want for obvious reasons.

Comment: Here we can see that newer versions solved this problem: https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/182

Comment: This might sound trite, but is your webdriver defined as static?  Mine wasn't, then I updated selenium and other tools, and things went wonky until someone suggested I mark it static and suddenly everything worked again.  It was the last thing I thought it could be because it was working dynamically for a long time through many versions.

Comment: I saw this post. This dealt with a very old build of 2015. Apparently there had been issues in the past but I am interested in the recent issue with the latest build(s). thanks for the efforts

Comment: @BillHileman - Using Selenide, one does not interact directly with webdriver since its being called under the hood. There is a way though to retrieve it using WebDriverRunner.getWebdriver() but it is never needed. In otherwords, I don't know how to mark it as static

Comment: Thanks, I'm not first-hand familiar with Selenide.

Comment: where is Andrei Solntsev?